# PopupMenu seems to have stopped working after upgrading Mathematica

Tags: manipulate

I have several files with popupmenus and they seem not to work since updating Mathematica to 12.0 
Is there something I should do?

Comment: I should say that I can change to SetterBar and all works fine

Comment: Nofify Wolfram Research. I hope you kept your old version.